# How can I use fiddler between my local WebRole and local Table Storage?

Tags: azure, fiddler, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a Webrole that is updating Azure Table storage, and I'd like to force Fiddler to see it.

What needs to be done to make this happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://ipv4.fiddler"

Answer (score 3):

If you're running against cloud storage, it should just work.  If you're running against development storage (on localhost), see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/partlycloudy/archive/2009/12/08/configuring-the-storage-client-with-connection-strings.aspx for how to configure the client library to use ipv4.fiddler as a proxy.

Comment: I don't believe this will work on Azure SDK v1.3 onwards due to the changes with IIS hosting. I have answered a question here for people that are struggling with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131913/azure-table-storage-exception-information/9464635#9464635